# If magic existed how would it affect technological progression?

Tags: technology, magic, science-fiction

I have created a fantasy world, that is in many ways defined as a high-fantasy vs Science-Fantasy world. The ability to perform magic is caused by using an extra element called "mana" to influence the laws of nature.

**What is Magic in this world:**
Much like what was seen in the movie "The Sorcerers Apprentice" fire is created by increasing the vibrations of the molecules. Or as seen in the books of "Earth-Sea Tales" by Ursula le Quin, where if you create a rain cloud over a field, the neighboring field might experience drought caused by dry weather. 
Mana is that which exists in the void between electrons and protons. And it is what a select group of individuals can utilize to perform "magic". The ability to use mana is through a genetic evolution or enhancement, i.e. some people are born with the ability to perform magic.

**Level of Technology:**
At the present year (1837), the ability to combine magic and mechanical engineering has been achieved and the largest constructions that exist to the known world are the airships, which closely resembles those seen in "Dungeon and Dragons Online: Stormreach - Guild Airships". However, these mechanical wonders are only for the wealthiest of nobles or the most prestigious armies. The regular farmer still uses an ox or workhorse for heavy labor, and the quarries still encompass massive armies of slaves for cutting stone through manual labor.
The Industrial Age is in its very infant state, with only a few guilds in the entire world that have encompassed it.

**Question:**
I'm currently in the process of expanding this worlds timeline to include both a modern era and that of a SciFi era much like Star Trek or Warhammer 40k and is wondering what year would space-flight become a day-to-day reality when you put magic into the mix?

I'm not intending to create a world where technology replaces magic, as that logic itself simply makes no sense. Instead, I'm looking for a fusion between magic and technology, i.e. a laser rifle would have a battery in the normal sci-fi world, but in this world - it could be powered by a mana container where the rifle acts as a catalyzer.

The year 1837 can be seen as late 1800's in comparison to our world.

**Edit in Response to Raditz_35 "What kind of magic can be performed?"**
Magic can perform a range of wonders in this world. Whether it be the classical Fireball or the teleportation of an object or living being from one location to another. Some magic goes into the divine, by scrying the very concept of reality - looking past the illusion and seeing what is true, or in another word being able to tell the future. Although the ability to ascertain the future or reality is subject to high individual cost, i.e. it can cause the death of the user. 
The most common magic or spells are those of offensive and defensive militaristic uses. Second most common, is the amplification or alteration of a physical aspect, i.e. making a person stronger, or repairing a castle after a siege.

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding *Yilmas*! If you have a moment please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. Have fun!

Comment: Oh ps: I should add that what you wrote under "What is magic in this world" I think is fine for a story, but has no meaning other than the vibration part, so one cannot possibly extrapolate a year from that. Basically your magic heats stuff up? Is that all it can do?

Comment: Perhaps relevant: [Sanderson's laws of magic](https://coppermind.net/wiki/Sanderson%27s_Laws_of_Magic). The question as posed is unanswerable, because we know very little about what can - and can't - be done with 'the magic'. As an additional crutch, it would suggest that 'technology' might advance faster overall. However, it might also means certain things just never get researched, because economics has a role to play. Cars would never get past curiousity stage if you had a magical beast that was strictly superior.

Comment: @Raditz_35 Right, magic can in general perform all the tricks from a regular DnD spellbook. What I was refering to with the examples were the "how" not the "what".

Comment: Could you tell us what a DnD spellbook can do? I know that some people here play this game, but if one needs to know some game in detail to answer your question, you are drastically reducing the amount of people that could help you here.

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding, Yilmas! Adding to what Raditz_35 wrote just previously, requiring someone who wants to answer your question to read separate material, and particularly so books, may be grounds for closing a question as *unclear what you are asking*. There is some discussion about this on [meta] in [Are questions based on movies okay?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3141/29) (which, despite the title, does not relate only to movies). If it's important, then incorporate the relevant parts into the question itself.

Comment: Updated the OP with relevant information.

Comment: Remember any sufficiently advanced technology is indistinguishable from magic. Similarly any sufficiently explained magic is indistinguishable from technology.

Comment: @sphennings you may win the philosophical musing award for today.

Comment: @James: http://www.girlgeniusonline.com/comic.php?date=20081205#.WjFDc3lpGHs

Comment: In this world could someone, for example, enchant an object to fly in a particular direction? If so what's the longest time such an enchantment could last while running. Do enchanted objects recharge themselves or need mages to recharge them? Can a mage enchant a metal bar to spin really fast? Is mana an exhaustible resource? can all the mana in an area be used up? does it come back? if so how fast and from where? D&D magic objects are pretty much at DM discretion and the spellbook includes "Wish". D&D magic is very broken and abusable for almost anything given a relaxed DM.

Comment: I would love to write an answer. One would have to see how long it takes to get from the understanding of our world in 1800 to the point where we can address the issues of space travel (radiation, pressure, material) and then to the point where there is any need for it to even exist on a daily basis, but I fear that the answer would be a thousand pages long and mostly filled with stuff you can make up yourself. My advice is: Think why you even need to know the exact year, what you need for space travel, what motivations there could be and then come back if you still have questions.

Comment: At the get go, my original thought was just to say some random large number, i.e. 50000 years. But then I started to think about the essential timespan of real life human existence, and came to the thought that 50000 years were simply a too big of a number, since we've gone from individual tribes to alliances of nations in just 2000 years, comparing that to 50000 and things go awry. Which led me to this question we are discussing. The thing that matters the most to me, is when the reader or player can look at something and go "huh, this sounds reasonable".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Consequences schmonsequences

**This is the dawn of the industrial age, the forests were turned to charcoal and ships.** Except it isn't, it came a lot sooner.

What magic gives is an easy way through the barriers that require technological advancement.

We needed to invent the steam engine, they needed to enchant a rod to spin continuously. We needed to invent the blast furnace to smelt iron, they just needed a fire spell.

The weight of an engine and fuel was a significant factor holding back powered long distance heavier than air flight. That's no longer a thing. Enchant a rod to spin, attach a gearbox and propellor and you don't even need to carry fuel. The same is true of iron ships needing vast steam engines, cars, trucks, trains, power stations. None of this requires the technological advancement that we needed.

**Magic is a bypass on every hard physical limitation on the world.**

This is why magic is so hard to work with, and the mix of magic and technology is almost impossible. It's very easy to create basic magical items on an industrial scale that could act as the engines for technological marvels and completely throw out the balance of a world.

Comment: So to restore balance, one would need to "limit" magic. And then go from there, perhaps with some historical references. I.e. lets say that 'one spell of a thrusting force' can last for X amount of time. Then correlate that with real life technological progression, while factoring in these "loop holes" or "bypasses".

Comment: @Yilmas, that's the general idea, find a way to prevent the magic from being too powerful, or even at all useful. One of the standard rules is that magic should only cause problems, not solve them.